# When can I play by myself?

Tags: rhythm-heaven-megamix

I want to do Challenge mode but I don't have friends that I can play with so I have to play solo. I just unlocked Challenge mode after the first gate,but if I try to go solo, I get told I have to do a few more things first.

When can I play Challenge mode solo?